# Test a list of proxies for authentication?

Tags: proxy, authentication

this is the situation:
I've bought a list of like 100 semi-private proxies but seems like a half of them are working and the other half are just asking for the login credentials again and again (seems like it's the proxy company fault).

So what I want to do is to mass check which proxies are working and which are not to send them the bad ones and ask for new ones instead.

Proxy list format:

```
ip:port:username:password
```

Thanks.

Comment: Should the proxies all have the same login credentials?

Comment: Yes. They all use the same login info.

Comment: Do you have Node installed? I think there might be a way to loop through them all with Node but I'd have to check.

Comment: Nope, I can install it and do everything necessary but I would need a guide for that.

Comment: I can link you to some instructions and I'm sure it's possible to write some code... just as soon as my Linux system stops being completely haywire that is.

Comment: No problem. Having to write someone an HTML5 based video player super-quick but I promise I will get on this one too as soon as I can!